Issue with INSERT INTO statement in Trino (version 389) using Hive Connector (version 3.1.3) and session setting for OVERWRITE
I'm encountering an issue while trying to insert into a table using the INSERT statement in Trino version 389 with the Hive Connector version 3.1.3. Specifically, when I set the session to overwrite, I receive the following exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported privilege name: ALTER

Here's the query I'm using:
SET SESSION hive.insert_existing_partitions_behavior = 'OVERWRITE';
insert into gl_ohq_qty_detail_dummy6 select * from gl_ohq_qty_detail_dummy5;

Below are the table DDLs for gl_ohq_qty_detail_dummy5 and gl_ohq_qty_detail_dummy6:
 CREATE TABLE hive.bucketdb.gl_ohq_qty_detail_dummy5 (
    tripduration varchar,
    starttime varchar,
    stoptime varchar,
    start_station varchar,
    start_station_name varchar,
    sslat varchar,
    sslon varchar,
    end_st varchar,
    end_s_name varchar,
    end_sta_lat varchar,
    end_sta_lon varchar,
    bike varchar,
    userty varchar,
    birth varchar,
    gender varchar
 )
 WITH (
    external_location = '<cloudbucket/folder1>',
    format = 'PARQUET'


 CREATE TABLE hive.bucketdb.gl_ohq_qty_detail_dummy6 (
    tripduration varchar,
    starttime varchar,
    stoptime varchar,
    start_station varchar,
    start_station_name varchar,
    sslat varchar,
    sslon varchar,
    end_st varchar,
    end_s_name varchar,
    end_sta_lat varchar,
    end_sta_lon varchar,
    bike varchar,
    userty varchar,
    birth varchar,
    gender varchar
 )
 WITH (
    external_location = '<cloudbucket/folder1>',
    format = 'PARQUET'
 ) 

The insertion works fine without the OVERWRITE session set, but I need to achieve the overwrite behavior.
Any insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried executing the INSERT INTO statement after removing the session "OVERWRITE" for empty table also, but the exception same as above.

That error message originates from the ThrifMetastore support in Trino.
It might be that hive.immutable-partitions is set to true for the catalog and that is causing the issue.
